# django session security popup on every page load

Tags: django, security, session, popup, warnings

I have installed django-session-security 2.6.1 on Django 1.9 to log out inactive users after two hours. I have the following in my settings:

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
        'session_security',
    ...
    ]
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'intro.middleware.director.SiteDirector',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'session_security.middleware.SessionSecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
    'intro.middleware.persistfilter.FilterPersistMiddleware',
    'content.middleware.content.ContentMiddleware',
    'intro.middleware.booking.BookingMiddleware',
    'common.middleware.accounts.PasswordChangeMiddleware'
)

    # session security
    SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER = 6900
    SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER = 7200
    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
    ...
```

and in base.html in the `<head>`

```
<script src="{% static "suit/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" %}"></script>
{% include 'session_security/all.html' %}
```

For every page load on the site if 10 seconds or more go by, the following popup occurs when navigating to another page on the *same* domain
[image]
This is not just on Firefox, but on Chrome. Searching for other people with similar issues does not yield helpful results, but indicates that the issue is caused by a javascript [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) command:

I have another project Django 1.6.1 and django-session-security 2.2.4. The only difference I can see is that in Django 1.9, I have to have `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True` or django crashes on any page reload, where is in Django 1.6.1, this is not set at all. Could it be some issue with my version of jquery? Any solutions would be appreciated.

Just to add that if I take

```
{% include 'session_security/all.html' %}
```

out of the base.html, then I no longer get the popups, but the warning does not display. The user still gets logged out though. One other note, I have

```
url(r'session_security/', include('session_security.urls')),
```

in urls.py.

**UPDATE**
There is some incompatibility with django-smart-selects,
and in particular

```
(function($) {
            var chainfield = "#id_supplier";
            var url = "/chaining/filter/money/Item/supplier/intro/BookingItem/item";
            var id = "#id_item";
            var value = undefined;
            var auto_choose = true;
            var empty_label = "---------";

            $(document).ready(function() {
                chainedfk.init(chainfield, url, id, value, empty_label, auto_choose);
            });
        })(jQuery || django.jQuery);
```

This appears to be injected in my template from
smart_selects/static/smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js

I can only guess that `jQuery || django.jQuery` means the variable jQuery OR django.jQuery according to which one is set, and that is passed to the function  which then... well then I am lost as to what this parameter is used for or where it is used.

I have tried specifying the jQuery that smart selects should use, but this has made no difference.
Looks like I should implement my own select update ajax call.

Comment: Do you have a form somewhere on your page?  E.G. a (hidden?) login dialog in the upper-right.  There was some discussion about preventing automatic navigation when forms were present to avoid data loss.

Comment: Yes, there is a form on the page, and it uses jQuery. Do you have a link to the discussion you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSS doesn't redirect a page with a form to ensure you don't lose form data.  There is a handler `confirmFormDiscard` that you can override to fix it.  There is some discussion in [issue #39](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/issues/39#issuecomment-158119087) in the repo, but the suggested fix appears to be:

```
{% include 'session_security/all.html' %}
<script>
   sessionSecurity.confirmFormDiscard = undefined;
</script>
```

This is also mentioned in the [FAQ](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/blob/master/docs/source/faq.rst).